# HTML report generation error in Jmeter 5.4.3

Tags: html, jmeter, report, performance-testing, load-testing

I am unable to generate the html report from the results .jtl file. I have jdk 17 on my machine and while giving the jmeter command to generate the report is giving me the below error message.

"An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 2 is not equal to fixed size 5"

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to the use of JDK 17 which is not supported by JMeter 5.4.3.

This bug is identified under:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65685

It is fixed in nightly build.

So you have 2 options:

- Use JDK < 17
- Use nightly build from here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/jmeter/nightlies/

The JMeter 5.5 release will be compatible with JDK 17.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I was able to generate the report by downgrading the jdk version to 15.

Comment: you’re welcome, happy it helped